# How can I add a DepdensOn attribute between CfnEndpoint and SecretTargetAttachment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm creating a database cluster and a DMS in the same stack. I'm using SecretsManager to pass the connection properties of the DB Cluster to the Endpoint. I've added a dependency between the endpoint and DB Cluster, but when I try to deploy the stack I get a problem like this:

```
11/14 | 10:08:49 AM | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::RDS::DBCluster                         | FooDBCluster
 11/14 | 10:08:51 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::DMS::Endpoint                          | fooendpoint
 11/14 | 10:08:51 AM | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment | FooDBSecretAttachment (FooDBSecretAttachmentE2E5F50F)
 12/14 | 10:08:52 AM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::DMS::Endpoint                          | fooendpoint Could not find a value associated with JSONKey in SecretString
```

The same does not happen if I have complemented the deployment of the DB Cluster some time before starting to deploy the Endpoint. This implies the host & port are not present in the Secret right after the DB Cluster has been created. Indeed in CDK they are declared after the DB Cluster.

However, I cannot add a dependency between the Endpoint and SecretTargetAttachment as SecretTargetAttackment is not a CfnResource type expected by the CfnEndpoint addDependencyOn method.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the dependency if you access the underlying node, like so.

```
if (secretsAttachment.node.defaultChild) {
      endPoint.node.addDependency(secretsAttachment.node.defaultChild);
}
```